# ASP.NET Core Endpoint - route all calls to specific route first

Tags: asp.net-core

What do I need to change this to route all requests to `/api/ShibAuth`?

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
  context.Response.Redirect("/api/ShibAuth");
});
```

The code above obviously routes any calls to root URL and I've already tried what I though was appropriate wildcard.

Comment: Did you mean you would like to route all the request to `/api/ShibAuth?`? Or any request comes you would like to append this `/api/ShibAuth` to any endpoint could you pleasee confrim?

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to change this to route all requests to /api/ShibAuth?

Well, if I correctly understand the requirement, you would like all of your request to redirect to this `/api/ShibAuth` route at the begining.

Certainly, we can implement above scenario using [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-7.0) class which provides the functionality to modify [`HttpRequest.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.path?view=net-7.0). Finally, rebuild the request URI and redirect to your expected path.  You can do as following

**Solution:**

```cs
app.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    var originalUrl = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();

    var routeToCallFirst = "api/ShibAuth";

    var updatedUrl = (new UriBuilder(originalUrl) { Host = context.Request.Host.Host, Path = routeToCallFirst }).Uri;

    context.Response.Redirect(updatedUrl.AbsoluteUri);
   
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Here, I am redirecting the all landing request to `/api/ShibAuth` controller from the middleware.